# Electrolux washer- motor pulley rotates but drive belt does not move

Tags: washer

The washer on my Electrolux stacked washer and dryer stopped operating.

The drive belt was broken, so I recently replaced the broken drive belt which fixed the agitation cycle.

However when the cycle gets to the spin cycle, I can see the motor pulley spinning/turning, but the drive belt does not move.  This causes a burning rubber smell (as the motor pulley spins against the non moving rubber belt) and eventually a load whinning noise.

This doesn't appear to be a new problem as the tenant was previously complaining of sporadic rubber burning smells and the same whinning noises in the past, so the it appears the spin cycle was sometimes working and sometimes not in the past.

Would this be indicative of some loose part?

Any suggestions, diagnosis or help on whether this can be a simple DIY and if it should be a service call would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the bearing of the drum wearing out.

As it ages it gets stiffer, requiring more force to rotate the drum.  The whining noise is as the belt and bearing get hot slipping against each other.

Drum bearings aren't easy to replace, and on some machines, impossible.

Try packing some grease into the bearing, trying not to get any on the belt of course.

Comment: Thanks Chenmunka, I think it may be beyond my DIY skills so most likely going to call a service person.

Comment: It could also be a belt tension problem if the belt is loose it will slip and burn, I would check this before trying to replace bearings a much bigger job.